# How to Filter variables for SP, to return only one value from many in SQL View

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, variables, filtering

In a SQL View, I have 5 boolean variables and one int variable.
out of 5 boolean variables only one variable will be true for a single data row,

### Task                        Type    boolVerySmall Datestart                  TagName

Architecture Setup -- Doc   Code    True    1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 Design_09

### idProject  boolsmall   boolMedium   boolLarge    boolVeryLarge    intHours

4     False      False  False      False               0

The above data is for one row... in this row, when I download the data from database to excel sheet, I have to display only the value which is true (boolVerySmall ,boolsmall,   boolMedium,boolLarge, boolVeryLarge, intHours) should be displayed in a single column,

I have written a Stored procedure for this. I am finding it difficult to get a particular row which has TRUE of intHours>0.

I am adding the sql query below. Please help me

> SELECT     dbo.tblResourceTaskList.txtTask, dbo.tblIndividualRelativeData.txtProductType, dbo.tblResourceTaskList.boolVerySmall, 
>   dbo.tblResourceTaskList.dtActualCompletionDate, dbo.tblEffortCodes.txtTagName, dbo.tblResourceTaskList.txtTaskNotes, dbo.tblResourceTaskList.idSubProject, dbo.tblResourceTaskList.idLaunch, dbo.tblResourceTaskList.idResource, dbo.tblResourceTaskList.boolSmall, dbo.tblResourceTaskList.boolMedium, dbo.tblResourceTaskList.boolLarge, dbo.tblResourceTaskList.boolVeryLarge, 
>   dbo.tblResourceTaskList.intDirectHours

FROM         dbo.tblResourceTaskList INNER JOIN dbo.tblProjectUsers ON dbo.tblResourceTaskList.idSubProject = dbo.tblProjectUsers.idSubProject AND 
dbo.tblResourceTaskList.idResource = dbo.tblProjectUsers.idUser INNER JOIN
dbo.tblLaunchInfo ON dbo.tblResourceTaskList.idLaunch = dbo.tblLaunchInfo.idLaunch INNER JOIN dbo.tblIndividualRelativeData ON dbo.tblResourceTaskList.idIndividualRelativeEffort = dbo.tblIndividualRelativeData.idIndividualRelativeEffort LEFT OUTER JOINdbo.tblEffortCodes ON dbo.tblResourceTaskList.idEffortCode = dbo.tblEffortCodes.idEffortCode

My stored procedure is 
SELECT txtTask, txtProductType, **boolVerySmall**, txtTagName, txtTaskNotes,

dtActualCompletionDate
     FROM tblResourceTaskList_View
    WHERE (idSubProject = @idSubProjectIndex )

as the first row from db has TRUE for boolVerySmall, then SP should return this value and if its other than that it should give that value.

Instead of filling *True* in excel sheet, I , have to assign VS for boolVerySmall, S - Small, M - Medium, L - Large VL- VeryLarge in the excelsheet.

So please help me how to work on this. 
1. Assigning shortnames (like VS... for the bool var's).
2. Returning only one value (boolverysmall or ... ) and assigning VS to that and fill it in excel.
3. if all the bools are false, then intHours should be assinged...

Kindly help me.

Thanks 
Ramm

Answer (score 0):

I am able to assign values to SP using CASE statements.

Now, its workign fine.

Thanks

Ramm